# Fade out image gradually while scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein

He guys,

I could use some help with a question I can't seem to find on the web.
I'm trying to fade an `<img>` within my header. I want this image to gradually fade out while scrolling down, when scrolling back up, the `<img>` should gradually fade back in.

Do I have to bind a scroll event to the opacity of the img? But how?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, change the numbers to your liking.

```
$(window).scroll(function(i){
    var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.element').css({'top': .7*scrollVar });
    $('.element').css({'opacity':( 100-scrollVar )/100});
})
```

Reference : https://coderwall.com/p/rxfefg

Answer (score 1):

Think you need something like this,

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var docPos = Math.round(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())/$(document).height() *100);
    $("#img").css("opacity",""+docPos/100+"");
});
```

Comment: 404 js fiddle broken

Comment: @Spir it's not my fault, some issue with the jsfiddle, anyway I removed the link.
Note: This code is working.